# modprobe: FATAL: Module fbcon not found. Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices

Tags: x11, xorg, configuration, kernel-modules, i915

I am using debian. I recently have purged X11 and xcfe4 and reinstalled them both but whenever I lauch `Xorg --configure` I get this:

```
(++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
modprobe: FATAL: Module fbcon not found in directory /lib/modules/$kernel
intel: waited 2020 ms for i915.ko driver to load
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
Configuration failed.
(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
```

Maybe the issue is with the content of **xorg.conf.new**? A snippet of the file:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
  Identifier     "X.org Configured"
  Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
  Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
  InputDevice   "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
  InputDevice   "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection
```

Comment: First thing to do is also to upgrade your kernel, as the newer X drivers may need newer kernel modules. If you have a custom kernel, you may need to enable some modules.

Comment: I already have the latest kernel.

Comment: same here. I'm using XPS13 but still have found no clue.

Answer (score 1):

Just by random, I ran into this problem just this hour with exact same output.

I myself disabled modeset with kernel command line "[...] `nomodeset i915.modeset=0`"

As https://askubuntu.com/a/137482 and even more https://askubuntu.com/a/193417 suggest, modeset is recommended.

When I reenabled modeset, driver was running fine.

P. S.: Today you typically don't configure the monitors with `xorg.conf` but use randr extension (so "`xrandr`" or "`arandr`" commands or your display managers configuration tool). See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Monitor_settings and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead

Comment: I never disabled modeset, as a matter of fact I don't have i915.modeset=0 in /etc/default/grub. I also tried to add i915 and intel_agp drivers in /etc/initramfs-tools/modules but it didn't work either.