# restoring xserver

Tags: linux-mint, x11, x-server

I was following this post https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=301627 but it did not work.

I deleted the `X11` folder (which did not exist before, if I remember correctly -- for sure, there was no `xorg.conf.d`) and now Mint (20) does not start with graphics anymore (only in recovery mode).

Here is attached the tail of `xsession`

Any idea of what I should do? (to avoid reinstalling the OS again?)

(`sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` did not help)

thanks a lot

[image]

ps: I was running on nvidia (`nvidia-driver-445` )

Comment: You don't normally need to configure X directly anymore.  Which desktop environment are you using (eg `cinnamon`)? Which videocard are you using (legacy nvidia drivers are available for older cards)?

Comment: yeah....but I destroyed something there... yes, I am on `cinnamon` with  `nvidia-driver-445`

Comment: and I have this same issue https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478663/modprobe-fatal-module-fbcon-not-found-number-of-created-screens-does-not-matc

Comment: here are some other screenshots, showing the  `xorg.config` file, error on `lightdm start` https://postimg.cc/gallery/cgZ3Jqh

Comment: (in case, the same question is posted here https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=336437)